# Structuring wiki pages with templates in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, web-part, page-layout, wiki

I need to create a custom template for SharePoint 2007 wiki pages. With ability to add multiple web parts zones on Wiki Page. Is it possible to do that, as I have read from online that wiki pages in SharePoint have only template file wkpstd.aspx.

I have seen solutions online which use jQuery, javascript and update the core wkpstd.aspx file. But, I cannot do that.

I have read many resources online, but could not find a clear solution yet.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420671/programmatically-editing-sharepoint-wiki-content

_http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-wiki-customizing.html/

And, many more. But, I could submit only two links as my reputation is below 10.

---

Thanks Janlester, your post was very helpful.

Now, I have found an resource for defining a wiki template here [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pavankumar/archive/2009/02/25/custom-wiki-site-definition-with-custom-document-template-for-creating-wiki-pages.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pavankumar/custom-wiki-site-definition-with-custom-document-template-for-creating-wiki-pages)

Now, I will follow this approach and will get back if I have problems.

Meanwhile please share if you have anything more to add.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code example in the url shows wiki pages created from a custom template. http://blog.ideseg.com/2007/sharepoint-destripando-el-wiki-2 (in spanish)

Note, as mentioned by jonlester this approach will always have wiki page unghosted.

nJoy :)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to create a custom layout for wiki pages in MOSS 2007, however there is a major drawback: pages created using the layout will be unghosted, which can lead to major performance problems.

We encountered this problem on a project a couple of years ago, and one of my coworkers describes the issue [here](http://collab.rdacorp.com/2008/06/customized-sharepoint-wiki-template.html).

You are basically stuck between accepting the potential performance problems, or modifying the OOTB `wkpstd.aspx` layout.

Comment: jonlaster,
Can you explain both these steps 
a. custom content type from wiki type
b. custom create wiki page
And, in the content type should I also specify my custom wkpstd.aspx template file. 
Thanks!